# Ошибка 404 при хостинге .net core на iis (только на windows server 2012)

Tags: .net, iis, .net-core, windows-server

Я написал сервис на .net core и хостил его у себя на пк во время разработки(iis). 
Хостил по гайду на мсдн. Но когда доделал приложение и решил его захостить на сервере, то получил ошибку 404.
В чем может быть проблема?
Вот web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Apteka_Service.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Только что убил кучу времени на аналогичную проблему с .net core2. Проверьте, установлен ли на сервере фреймворк и библиотека интеграции IIS, после установки не помешает перегрузиться на всякий случай.

В моём конкретном случае в Program.cs не прописал интеграцию с IIS.

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseIISIntegration()  // << вот эта строчка
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

При этом на машине разработчика в IIS Express работает хорошо.

Comment: Пробовал много раз, не помогло..)
В итоге просто создал новый проект .net core web-api и просто перенёс туда контроллеры. И о чудо, он заработал.